# what is best to serve

Tags: adjectives, definite-article, infinitives, superlatives

a. What is best to serve at our dinner party?

b. What is the best to serve at our dinner party?

c. Among the dishes on that list, which is best to serve at our dinner party?

d. Among the dishes on that list, which is the best to serve at our dinner party?

Which of the above sentences are grammatically correct?

I think (b) is incorrect since we are choosing from an unlimited list of possibilities, however if we had 'the best thing' or 'the best dish' or something like that then it would be fine.

Comment: 'Which is the best one to serve...?'

Comment: I'd prefer the first version - but with an extra pronoun: *What is **it** best to serve at our dinner party?* Just as we normally ask *Where is it best to eat in this town?* rather than *Where is best to eat in this town?*

Answer (score 1):

Idiomatically, OP's first version is the most natural - [*but with the inclusion of a pronoun...*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Where%20is%20best%20to%2CWhere%20is%20it%20best%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWhere%20is%20best%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWhere%20is%20it%20best%20to%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

...hence...

> ***What is it best to serve at our dinner party?***

I wouldn't say it's syntactically *invalid* to discard that pronoun, and/or to introduce the definite article ***the*** before ***best***, but idiomatically those are both at least "less common" stylistic choices.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find any of them idiomatic in the given context.

Asking "what is best" is more given to a more general context than just one single event such as your own dinner party. For example, one might ask "what is best to serve at **a** dinner party?", which in effect asks what foods are most suited for the context of a dinner party, rather than just your own.

Having decided that you are already going to throw a dinner party, with or without a shortlist of options, it would be more idiomatic and logical to ask "*what shall we serve* at our dinner party?", as I would expect you to already have some comprehension of dinner party etiquette which would rule out certain types of food anyway.